# What is wrong with my GEs subscription to Orion CB?

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

Just realised something is wrong with my fiware infrastructure. IoT-Agent, LWM2M client running (wakaama implementation) and can see device and entities in MongoDB.

Thinking all is well, until I was informed I can check subscriptions to Orion, when I understand Orion has no subscription for IOTAgent, Cygnus etc..

```
$ curl -X GET http://localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions
[]
```

I though the IOT-Agent is subscribing automatically (when using real device). Should I manually subscribe for the IOTAgent as well as Cygnus with Orion (or they do this automatically)

Please what is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IOTAgent:

- Automatically register new devices in Orion as part of the device provisioning procedure. This registration is used to forward queries/updates in the flows related with lazy attributes and commands.
- IOTAgent doesn't subscribe to Orion by default, only if bidirectional pluging is used. In that case the agent creates the subscription automatically.

Cygnus:

- It doesn't subscribe to Orion by default. Note that Cygnus doesn't know in advance which entities and attributes do you want to persist in its sinks, so it makes sense the user (who has that knowledge) create the subscription. Check [this part](https://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/master/cygnus-ngsi/user_and_programmer_guide/connecting_orion/index.html) of the Cygnus documentation about it.

You can check existing registrations and subscriptions in Context Broker using the following operations, respectively:

- `GET /v2/registrations`
- `GET /v2/subscriptions`

Note these operations are service aware and service path aware. Thus, you have to set the right `fiware-service` and `fiware-servicepath` HTTP request headers in order to get the rigth information. Have a look to the [documentation on service](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/multitenancy/index.html) and the [documentation on service path](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/service_path/index.html) related this.

Comment: Useful information indeed, I mislead myself for long time. But how is bidirectional plug-in used please?

Comment: Everything checked, and now I can view all subscriptions. Many thanks.

Comment: Great! Please add +1 and check the answer as valid. This is not to feed my ego :) but to let other users know about the usefulness of the answer.